# Having trouble in observing a liveData list in my viewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, observers, mutablelivedata

I am displaying markers from my database on my map, But i have a filter for the user from where he can adjust the time and the markers will show in that time.  I want to observe the list that is updated each time when the user changes the time filter. He selects a start time and end time and I query from the database to get a list with that condition .. I want to observe this list? How can I do that?

my ViewModel:

```
      public MediatorLiveData<List<LocationTracking>> fetchData(LiveData<List<LocationTracking>> source){
    if (oldSource == null){
        oldSource = source;
    } else {
        list.removeSource(oldSource);
    }
    list.addSource(source, locationTrackings -> {
        list.postValue(locationTrackings);
    });
    return list;
}
```

And in my activity I'm doing this:

My callback isn't called for on change when a new value is inserted in my database. Any help would be highly appreciated.

When the user wants to see whole list without time filter.

```
mViewModel.fetchData(mViewModel.getFilteredLocationList(
                        mDataRange.get(0).getTimeStamp(),
                        mDataRange.get(1).getTimeStamp()
                )).observe(this,mFilteredListObserver);
```

When the user selects a time Filter.

```
mViewModel.fetchData(mViewModel.getFilteredLocationList(
                data.getLongExtra(LocationsFilterActivity.START_TIME, 0),
                data.getLongExtra(LocationsFilterActivity.END_TIME, 0)
        )).observe(this,mFilteredListObserver);
```

Comment: Are you getting the markers from database when coming to the screen first time ?

Comment: @MuhammadAwais
No, I get them only on the click of a button or when the user sets the time range .

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah have you solved your issue? Please let me know if my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with a similar problem. Once you understand the solution it's quite simple. You need to do something like this in your ViewModel:

```
private MutableLiveData<DataRange> dataRange = new MutableLiveData<DataRange>();
public LiveData<List<LocationTracking>> list = Transformations.switchMap(dataRange, 
newDataRangeValue -> getFilteredLocationList(
        newDataRangeValue.get(0).getTimeStamp(),
        newDataRangeValue.get(1).getTimeStamp())
);

public void onDataRangeChanged(DataRange dataRange) {
    this.dataRange.setValue(dataRange);
}
```

In your Activity observe the `list`. The `switchMap()` method will listen for any changes on `dataRange` so if you do `mViewModel.onDataRangeChanged(newDataRange)`, `getFilteredLocationList()` will be called again and `list` will be updated in Activity.

I highly recommend reading [this great article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7).